# python dict.keys() not returning all values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I am new to python programming. I am attempting to make a program that serves as an interactive dictionary of skyrim potion effects in order to practice coding spell check functions.

The is the relevant bits of my code.

```
effects = {'curedisease' : ['Charred Skeever Hide', 'Felsaad Tern Feathers', 'Hawk Feathers', 'Mudcrab Chitin', 'Vampire Dust'], 'damagehealth' : ['Crimson Nirnroot', 'Deathbell', 'Ectoplasm', 'Emperor Parasol Moss', 'Falmer Ear', 'Human Flesh', 'Human Heart', 'Imp Stool', 'Jarrin Root', 'Nightshade', 'Nirnroot', 'Poison Bloom', 'Red Mountain Flower', 'River Betty', 'Skeever Tail', 'Small Antlers', 'Troll Fat', 'Void Salts'], 'damagemagicka' : ['Butterfly Wing',' Chaurus Eggs', 'Daedra Heart', 'Eye of Sabre Cat', 'Glow Dust', 'Hagraven Feathers', 'Hanging Moss', 'Human Heart', 'Jarrin Root', 'Luna Moth Wing', "Namira's Rot", 'Nordic Barnacle', 'Trama Root'], 'damageMagikaregen' : ['Bear Claws', 'Blue Butterfly Wing', 'Blue Mountain Flower', 'Chicken\'s Egg', 'Glow Dust', 'Hanging Moss', 'Human Heart', 'Jarrin Root', 'Nightshade', 'Spider Egg', 'Spriggan Sap'], 'damagestamina' : ['Blisterwort', 'Blue Butterfly Wing', 'Bone Meal', 'Canis Root', 'Crimson Nirnroot', 'Cyrodilic Spadetail', 'Giant\'s Toe', 'Jarrin Root', 'Nirnroot', 'Rock Warbler Egg', 'Spider Egg'], 'damagestaminasegen' : ['Creep Cluster', 'Daedra Heart', 'Frost Mirriam', 'Giant\'s Toe', 'Histcarp', 'Juniper Berries', 'Large Antlers', 'Silverside Perch', 'Skeever Tail', 'Wheat'], 'fear' : ['Blue Dartwing', 'Cyrodilic Spadetail', 'Daedra Heart', 'Namira\'s Rot', 'Powdered Mammoth Tusk'], 'fortifyalteration' : ['Grass Pod', 'River Betty', 'Spriggan Sap'], 'fortifybarter' : ['Butterfly Wing', 'Dragon\'s Tongue', 'Hagraven Claw', 'Tundra Cotton'], 'fortifyblock' : ['Bleeding Crown', 'Briar Heart', 'Honeycomb', 'Pearl', 'Slaughterfish Scales', 'Tundra Cotton'], 'fortifycarryWeight' : ['Creep Cluster', 'Giant\'s Toe', 'Hawk Beak', 'River Betty', 'Scaly Pholiata', 'Wisp Wrappings'], 'fortifyconjuration' : ['Blue Butterfly Wing', 'Blue Mountain Flower', 'Bone Meal', 'Frost Salts', 'Hagraven Feathers', 'Lavender'], 'fortifydestruction' : ['Beehive Husk', 'Ectoplasm', 'Glow Dust', 'Glowing Mushroom', 'Nightshade', 'Wisp Wrappings'], 'fortifyenchanting' : ['Blue Butterfly Wing', 'Hagraven Claw', 'Snowberries', 'Spriggan Sap'], 'fortifyhealth' : ['Bear Claws', 'Blue Mountain Flower', 'Giant\'s Toe', 'Glowing Mushroom', 'Hanging Moss', 'Wheat'], 'fortifyheavyarmor' : ['Ice Wraith Teeth', 'Sabre Cat Tooth', 'Slaughterfish Scales', 'Thistle Branch', 'White Cap'], 'fortifyillusion' : ['Dragon\'s Tongue', 'Dwarven Oil', 'Mora Tapinella', 'Scaly Pholiata', 'Taproot'], 'fortifylightarmor' : ['Ice Wraith Teeth', 'Sabre Cat Tooth', 'Slaughterfish Scales', 'Thistle Branch', 'White Cap'], 'fortifylockpicking' : ['Falmer Ear', 'Namira\'s Rot', 'Pine Thrush Egg', 'Spider Egg'], 'fortifymagicka   ' : ['Briar Heart', 'Ectoplasm', 'Histcarp', 'Jazbay Grapes', 'Red Mountain Flower', 'Tundra Cotton', 'Void Salts'], 'fortifymarksman' : ['Canis Root', 'Elves Ear', 'Juniper Berries', 'Spider Egg'], 'fortifyonehanded' : ['Bear Claws', 'Canis Root', 'Hanging Moss', 'Hawk Feathers', 'Rock Warbler Egg', 'Small Pearl'], 'fortifypickpocket' : ['Blue Dartwing', 'Nordic Barnacle', 'Orange Dartwing', 'Slaughterfish Egg'], 'fortifyrestoration' : ['Abecean Longfin', 'Cyrodilic Spadetail', 'Salt Pile', 'Small Antlers', 'Small Pearl'], 'fortifysmithing' : ['Blisterwort', 'Glowing Mushroom', 'Sabre Cat Tooth', 'Spriggan Sap'], 'fortifysneak' : ['Abecean Longfin', 'Beehive Husk', 'Frost Mirriam', 'Hawk Feathers', 'Human Flesh', 'Powdered Mammoth Tusk', 'Purple Mountain Flower'], 'fortifystamina' : ['Chaurus Eggs', 'Garlic', 'Large Antlers', 'Lavender', 'Slaughterfish Egg', 'Torchbug Thorax'], 'lingeringdamagehealth' : ['Imp Stool', 'Mora Tapinella', 'Orange Dartwing', 'Slaughterfish Egg', 'Slaughterfish Scales'], 'lingeringdamagemagicka' : ['Hagraven Claw', 'Purple Mountain Flower', 'Swamp Fungal Pod', 'Torchbug Thorax', 'Wheat'], 'lingeringdamagestamina' : ['Butterfly Wing', 'Chicken\'s Egg', 'Nightshade', 'Small Antlers'], 'paralysis' : ['Briar Heart', 'Canis Root', 'Human Flesh', 'Imp Stool', 'Swamp Fungal Pod'], 'ravagehealth' : ['Cyrodilic Spadetail', 'Eye of Sabre Cat', 'Giant Lichen', 'Jazbay Grapes', 'Silverside Perch', 'Skeever Tail'], 'ravagemagicka' : ['Frost Mirriam', 'Grass Pod', 'Lavender', 'Orange Dartwing', 'Red Mountain Flower', 'White Cap'], 'ravagestamina' : ['Bee', 'Bone Meal', 'Deathbell', 'Honeycomb', 'Thistle Branch'], 'regeneratehealth' : ['Garlic', 'Juniper Berries', 'Luna Moth Wing', 'Namira\'s Rot', 'Nordic Barnacle', 'Vampire Dust'], 'regeneratemagicka' : ['Dwarven Oil', 'Fire Salts', 'Garlic', 'Jazbay Grapes', 'Moon Sugar', 'Salt Pile', 'Taproot'], 'regeneratestamina' : ['Bee', 'Fly Amanita', 'Mora Tapinella', 'Scaly Pholiata'], 'resistfire' : ['Bone Meal', 'Dragon\'s Tongue', 'Elves Ear', 'Fire Salts', 'Fly Amanita', 'Mudcrab Chitin', 'Snowberries'], 'resistfrost' : ['Frost Mirriam', 'Frost Salts', 'Hawk Beak', 'Moon Sugar', 'Purple Mountain Flower', 'Silverside Perch', 'Slaughterfish Scales', 'Small Pearl', 'Snowberries', 'Thistle Branch'], 'resistmagic' : ['Bleeding Crown', 'Chicken\'s Egg', 'Crimson Nirnroot', 'Hagraven Claw', 'Lavender', 'Nirnroot', 'Tundra Cotton', 'Void Salts', 'Wisp Wrappings'], 'resistpoison' : ['Beehive Husk', 'Charred Skeever Hide', 'Falmer Ear', 'Garlic', 'Grass Pod', 'Mudcrab Chitin', 'Slaughterfish Egg', 'Thistle Branch', 'Troll Fat'], 'resistshock' : ['Blue Dartwing', 'Glow Dust', 'Glowing Mushroom', 'Hawk Beak', 'Pearl', 'Pine Thrush Egg', 'Snowberries', 'Swamp Fungal Pod'], 'restorehealth' : ['Blisterwort', 'Blue Dartwing', 'Blue Mountain Flower', 'Butterfly Wing', 'Charred Skeever Hide', 'Daedra Heart', 'Eye of Sabre Cat', 'Imp Stool', 'Rock Warbler Egg', 'Swamp Fungal Pod', 'Wheat'], 'restoremagicka ' : ['Briar Heart', 'Creep Cluster', 'Dwarven Oil', 'Ectoplasm', 'Elves Ear', 'Fire Salts', 'Frost Salts', 'Giant Lichen', 'Grass Pod', 'Human Flesh', 'Moon Sugar', 'Mora Tapinella', 'Pearl', 'Red Mountain Flower', 'Taproot', 'Vampire Dust', 'White Cap']}

effectslist = effects.keys()
print (effectslist)
```

The trouble is that effectslist will not contain all keys in the dictionary effects.  I am unclear on whether it is leaving out the same keys all the time or cycling the list but I need it to create a complete list of the strings used as keys in the effects dictionary.

Can anybody please explain to me why it is not making a full list and what I can do to create a full list?

Thank you

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with that code. It works completely fine.

Answer (score 1):

> The trouble is that effectslist will not contain all keys in the dictionary effects.

Actually, no. It does contain all the keys.

First of all, `keys()` returns the correct number of elements:

```
>>> len(effects)
44
>>> len(effects.keys())
44
```

Secondly, all elements it returns are unique:

```
>>> len(set(effects.keys()))
44
```

Finally, every returned key is present in the dictionary:

```
>>> all(k in effects for k in effects.keys())
True
```

If you were to try and find a specific key that's not returned by `.keys()`, I am sure you will discover that there isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the code myself and it appears that `len(effects)==len(effectslist)`, so by all accounts it is returning the full list. What gives you the idea that it is not returning the full list? Remember that dictionaries do not exist in a fixed order - so when you query for the keys they won't be in the same order as you entered them.